# Load shared object using ctyped.cdll.loadLibrary from dist-packages folder

Tags: c, python-3.x, shared-libraries, setuptools

I created this `setup.py` to compile a `libDIV.so` shared library and install it.

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

libDIV = Extension(
  'DIV',
  sources = ['example.c']
)

setup (
  name = 'divv',
  version = '0.1',
  description = 'DIVV, you want it',
  ext_modules = [libDIV],
  packages = [''],
  package_data={'': ['libDIV.so']}
)
```

After running `python3 setup.py install`, the shared library is placed in the dist-packages folder as:

```py
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/DIV.cpython-34m.so
```

In an extra file `example.py` I want to load the library using `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary`, such that `example.py` can wrap it's functionality in more elegant, type checked python functions.

```py
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('DIV.so') # not sure what to do here

def divide_modulo(a, b):
  div = ctypes.c_int(0)
  rest = ctypes.c_int(0)
  lib.divide_modulo(a, b, ctypes.byref(div), ctypes.byref(rest))
  return (div.value, rest.value)

print(divide_modulo(11, 4))

class DynamicArray(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = [("n", ctypes.c_int), ("r", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))]
```

However I'm not sure how to pass the right file name and location for the created shared object file.

How should I distribute / configure setup.py for a library of c-files which build into a shared library and some python code to wrap the c-functionality?

For completeness, this is example.c:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>

void divide_modulo(int a, int b, int *div, int *rest)
{
*div  = a / b;
*rest = a % b;
}

typedef struct dynamic_array {
  int n;
  int *r;
} dynamic_array;

dynamic_array return_dynamic_array(int n)
{
  dynamic_array r;
  r.n = n;
  r.r = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
  unsigned int i = 0;
  for (; i < n; ++i)
  r.r[i] = i;
  return r;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Currently I do this to find the file name:

```py
import ctypes, numpy, site, os.path
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

so_file = next(
    os.path.join(directory, filename)
    for directory in site.getsitepackages()
    for filename in os.listdir(directory)
    if filename.startswith("DIV.") and filename.endswith(".so")
)
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(so_file)
```

But honestly, this is quite smelly. I'm not sure the file will always be called `DIV.something.so` and that vice versa that other files are not named like this.

Comment: Have you found better solution? I just posted a similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434262).

Comment: I don't even vaguely remember what I was doing here, but I would not think so, sorry.