# python setup.py build ctypes.CDLL: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python

I have implemented a ctypes wrapper called api.c, and I have the structure:

```
lib/api.c
foo.py
setup.py
```

Compiling api.c manually and calling `ctypes.CDLL(path+'lib/api.so')` inside `foo.py` works, where  `path` is the absolute pathname.

Now, I want distribute it with setup.py:

```
setup(name='foo',
      ext_modules=[Extension('lib.api', ['lib/api.c'])]
     )
```

Installing with `python setup.py develop -u --user` works, too, because `api.so` appears in `lib/`.

With `python setup.py install --user` the code is compiled, too, but `api.so` appears in some `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/lib` folder.
Therefore importing the module results in
`OSError: /.../lib/api.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So how can I distribute it with `install` and what should be the value of `path`?

related issues:
[How to include a shared C library in a Python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121352)

Comment: I just found a similar unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391655.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333210

Comment: and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that when adding the argument `py_modules=['foo']` to `setup`,
`python setup.py install` installed it properly in the site-packages directory. Thus

```
setup(name='foo',
      py_modules=['foo'],
      ext_modules=[Extension('lib.api', ['lib/api.c'])]
     )
```